# Get join date of a Facebook user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get the join date in facebook API?

Im looking on the API docs but I can't find anything.

reason: we don't want a user to register using new created account in our site to avoid multiple dummy accounts? Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no such field in the Graph API. Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/

Comment: yup. if you can´t find it in the API docs, it´s probably not possible :) - +1 for you, sir.